# How to convert date format stored in a variable in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I need to convert the date format. Here is mine:

```
> date
      date
1   16.08.2013
2   17.08.2013
3   18.08.2013
```

The format I desire is

```
> date
       date
1   2013-08-16
2   2013-08-17
3   2013-08-18
```

I tried`as.Date`, but could not make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you take a look at the help file? `help("as.Date")`

Comment: Yes, I did. I used `format(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")` , but nothing changed.

Comment: You have to supply the format that is currently in use (not the desired one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
date$date <- as.Date(as.character(date$date),format="%d.%m.%Y")
```

Comment: I did, but here is the error massage ` do not know how to convert 'date$date' to class "Date"` . Is that because I got `date` from a text file?

Comment: maybe when you imported your file from the text file it got converted to a factor. add this to the code provided by road_to_quantdom `date$date <- as.Date(as.character(date$date),format="%d.%m.%Y")`

Comment: @Günal did you try Colin's suggestion?

Comment: @Günal do you mind accepting the answer as correct then please